# kivy python: Invalid instance in App.root

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am very new to kivy python, so I don't know what really went wrong in this code. I am getting error : Invalid instance in App.root  .  Please help me to tackle this....

I was making an object detection program in kivy python....
IF any more error please also resolve that or whatever went wrong..

```
from __future__ import division
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from math import cos, sin 

green = (0, 255, 0)

class find_obj():
    def show(self, image):
        #figure size in inches
        plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
        plt.imshow(image, interpolation='nearest')

    def overlay_mask(self, mask, image):
        #mask the mask rgb
        rgb_mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

        img = self.cv2.addWeighted(rgb_mask, 0.5, self.image, 0.5, 0)
        return img

   def find_biggest_contour(self, image):
        #copy image
        image = image.copy()
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        #to find biggest contour
        contour_sizes = [(cv2.contourArea(contour), contour) for contour in contours]
        biggest_contour = max(contour_sizes, key=lambda x: x[0])[1]

        #return the biggest contour
        mask = self.np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [biggest_contour], -1, 255, -1)
        return biggest_contour, mask

    def circle_contour(self, image, contour):

        #bounding ellipse
        image_with_ellipse = self.image.copy()
        ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(contour)
        #add it
        cv2.ellipse(image_with_ellipse, ellipse, green, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        return image_with_ellipse

    def find_object(self, image):
        #RGB is red green blue
        #BGR is blue green red
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
        #to scale the image
        max_dimension = max(image.shape)
        scale = 700/max_dimension
        image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=scale, fy=scale)

        #to clean the image 
        image_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (7,7), 0)
        image_blur_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image_blur, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

        #defining the filters by color
        min_red = np.array([0,100, 80])
        max_red = np.array([10,256, 256])

        mask1 = cv2.inRange(image_blur_hsv, min_red, max_red)

        #filter by brightness
        min_red2 = np.array([170,100,80])
        max_red2 = np.array([100,256,256])

        mask2 = cv2.inRange(image_blur_hsv, min_red2, max_red2)

        mask = mask1 + mask2

        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (15,15))
        mask_closed = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
        mask_clean = cv2.morphologyEx(mask_closed, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

        big_object_contour, mask_object = find_biggest_contour(mask_clean)

        overlay = overlay_mask(mask_clean, image)

        circled = circle_contour(overlay, big_object_contour)
        show(circled)

        #convert back to original color scheme
        bgr = cv2.cvtColor(circled, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        return bgr
    
    def ret_img(self):
        image = cv2.imread('apple.jpeg')
        result = self.find_object(image)
        #write the new image
        cv2.imwrite('apple2.jpeg', result)

class face(App):
    def build(self):
        a = find_obj()
        return a


if __name__ == '__main__':
     face().run()
     #img = Image(source = "apple2.jpeg")
     #print(img)
     cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thank you .... In advance.....

Comment: The return from your `build()` method must be a `Widget`. the `find_obj` class is not a `Widget`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I still didn't understand. How to do this.....     Please can you re- code it....

Comment: The return of your `build()` method will be displayed as the GUI for your App. You need to decide what your GUI should look like, then build that, and return it.